# Build error in building of a project has the INET reference

Tags: c++, omnet++

I want to simulate a project including the INET reference, but the following error has generated. How to fix it?

```
.
.
.
Creating executable: ../out/clang-debug/src/D2DCommunication_dbg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lINET_dbg
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [../out/clang-debug/src/D2DCommunication_dbg] Error 1
Makefile:109: recipe for target '../out/clang-debug/src/D2DCommunication_dbg' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/reza/omnetpp/omnetpp-5.6.1/samples/D2DCommunication/src'
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

19:24:15 Build Failed. 5 errors, 2 warnings. (took 6s.698ms)
```

Comment: Could you check whether `libINET_dbg.so` exists in `src` of your INET directory?

Comment: How to check it?(By menu). Some other projects that depend on the Inet, have no problem in compiling and building.

Comment: There are many ways of checking whether a file exists. For example, open console, go to directory where you have INET, go to src, type `ls -al`. Or open graphical explorer, change directory to your INET, go to src and check whether you can see desired file. On you may use `find` command...

Comment: I check the src folder in the Inet directory, the libINET.so was available. The problem should be exists in D2DCommunication project.

Comment: Could you check whether `libINET_dbg.so` exists?

Comment: Yes, I could check the src folder in the Inet directory(~/omnetpp/omnetpp-5.6.1/samples/inet4/src$ ls -al), the libINET.so was exist, not libINET_dbg.so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237011/discussion-between-reza-and-jerzy-d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have built INET in release mode, while the project referenced to INET is built in debug mode. However, both projects must be built in the same mode.
Assuming that you need debug mode, in Eclipse right click in INET, chose `Build Configurations`, then `Set Active` and select `gcc-debug` or `debug`.